# pymongo group by multiple keys and concat values array based on another key

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have mongo documents of following structure.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "615eb369514212cb0a27ba74"
},
"FragCount": 0,
"ValueMapping": 3,
"DataType": 19,
"BurstId": 55,
"SensorNodeId": "29a24a99",
"Values": [5, 0, -5, 8, -2, -6, 2, -2, 3, -3, 0, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, -2, 3, 1, -4, 1, 0, -1, 5, -5, 2, -1, -1, 0, 0, 4, -3, -1, 2, 13, -15, 13, -13, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 7, -8, 9, -5, -4, 4, -4, 1, 3, -4, 4, -4, 3, -2, -1, 5, -5, 10, -5, -5, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1],
"GatewayId": "7d62eb89",
"BurstDataOffset": 0,
"DataSize": 1002,
"Type": "burst",
"MeasurementId": 110,
"MeasurementTimeInterval": 150
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "615eb369514212cb0a27ba75"
    },
    "FragCount": 1,
    "ValueMapping": 3,
    "DataType": 19,
    "BurstId": 55,
    "SensorNodeId": "29a24a99",
    "Values": [1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 3, -3, 3, 0, -3, 3, -3, 5, 1, -6, 5, -5, 5, -2, -3, 3, 0, -3, 4, -4, 3, -2, -1, 3, -3, 4, -3, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "GatewayId": "7d62eb89",
    "BurstDataOffset": 99,
    "DataSize": 1002,
    "Type": "burst",
    "MeasurementId": 110,
    "MeasurementTimeInterval": 150
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "615eb369514212cb0a27ba76"
    },
    "FragCount": 2,
    "ValueMapping": 3,
    "DataType": 19,
    "BurstId": 55,
    "SensorNodeId": "29a24a99",
    "Values": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "GatewayId": "7d62eb89",
    "BurstDataOffset": 198,
    "DataSize": 1002,
    "Type": "burst",
    "MeasurementId": 110,
    "MeasurementTimeInterval": 150
}
```

I need to query data by MeasurementId and SensorNodeId, combination of the 2 will always be distinct. Then each combination has 3 distinct BurstIds. For each burstID ValueMapping is constant. For each burstID I want to be able to concat Values array, the order of this concat is also important. It needs to concat based on FragCount which is always 1-n.

The final structure needs to be something like:

```
[
{
    "MeasurementID": xxx,
    "SensorNodeID": 'YYYYY',
    "GatewayID": 'YYYYY',
    "{ValueMapping key 1}" : [Concatenated values array],
    "{ValueMapping key 2}" : [Concatenated values array],
    "{ValueMapping key 3}" : [Concatenated values array],
},

{
    "MeasurementID": xxx,
    "SensorNodeID": 'YYYYY',
    "GatewayID": 'YYYYY',
    "{ValueMapping key 1}" : [Concatenated values array],
    "{ValueMapping key 2}" : [Concatenated values array],
    "{ValueMapping key 3}" : [Concatenated values array],
},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        '$sort': {
            "BurstId": 1,
            'FragCount': 1
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'SensorNodeId': '$SensorNodeId',
                'MeasurementId': '$MeasurementId',
                'GatewayId': '$GatewayId',
                'ValueMapping': '$ValueMapping'
            },
            'BurstId': { '$first': '$BurstId' },
            'Values': {
                '$push': '$Values'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$sort': {
            "BurstId": 1
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {
                'SensorNodeId': '$_id.SensorNodeId',
                'MeasurementId': '$_id.MeasurementId',
                'GatewayId': '$_id.GatewayId',
            },
            'BurstId': { '$push': '$BurstId' },
            'ValueMapping': {
                '$push': {
                    'k': { '$concat': [{ '$toString': "$_id.ValueMapping" }] }, 'v': {
                        "$reduce": {
                            "input": "$Values",
                            "initialValue": [],
                            "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$replaceRoot': {
            'newRoot': {
                '$mergeObjects': [{
                    'SensorNodeId': '$_id.SensorNodeId',
                    'MeasurementId': '$_id.MeasurementId',
                    'GatewayId': '$_id.GatewayId',
                }, { '$arrayToObject': "$ValueMapping" },]
            }
        }
    }
])
```